# Adding a view dynamically with in the same view

Tags: iphone, uiview

i have a view which contains some text fields and picker views and one button,when clicked on the button all these textfields and picker view should appear again in the same view.Now how should i take the initial view and how to load the same view with the previous view when clicked on the button.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: how did you create those text fields and picker.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Frames an Adding subview (text fields and picker views) on the button click , you can appear those subviews to the main view.

Or else you can initially put them all in the main view and initially hide them. And on the button click set them `Hidden : NO`.

Comment: i am unable to get your answer..bcoz initially it should appear and after filling that textfields if at all i require the same fields again i want to click on button saying that the same fields should appear again with the previous fields

Comment: You mean you want to make appear text fields again with no text ??

Comment: s..this means loading the same xib again with in the same view with previous view appearing

Comment: Ok. Then on button click you can make `textfield.text = @""`.

Comment: i need to appear the previously filled textfield and at the same time i need newly textfield on the view

Comment: Can u give me the screen shot , so that i can get what you exactly want ?

Comment: i dont have chance for uploading scrennshot

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach:

1. On your View controller :  Add a button and a UIScrollView.
2. Create an independent view say MyView containing all your TextFields and pickers. (you can   create this via xib or via code)
3. In ViewDidLoad method of your controller add this MyView on UIScrollView.
4. On onButtonPressed similarly add MyView on UIScrollView.

Comment: can you explain in detail one i have added all the textfields and picker view through IB please tell me by a sample code if possible..

Comment: wt actually this subviews here..should we declare anything for that subviews

Comment: if write code - (void)viewDidLoad {

[textField1 removeFromSuperview];
[textField2 removeFromSuperview];
[pickerView removeFromSuperview];

.....
} the textfields r not getting displayed in the view.

Comment: like i have a view which display textfield1 and textfield2 n one button ,when clicked on this button again textfield1 and textfield2 along with new copy of textfield1 and textfield2 with the button should display that means totally 4 textfields should display when clicked on the button.if i again clicked on the button again two new textfields along with four old textfields should display

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem then this code might help you. I am adding only text field on button click event. So I think it might give you idea for another views and you can do the same with another views. I am giving you  .m file, hope you can write .h file. Here is my .m file looks like -

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize btn = _btn; // IBOutlet of UIButton
@synthesize txtFieldOne = _txtFieldOne; // IBOutlet of UITextField
@synthesize txtFieldTwo = _txtFieldTwo; // IBOutlet of UITextField

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    newYCoordinateForNewTxtFld = 40.0; // newYCoordinateForNewTxtFld is of type CGFloat
    frame = self.txtFieldTwo.frame;    // frame is of type CGRect

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return true;

}

// TextField Delegate Method you might required in your project
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{

    // I am giving u a simple idea, so written simple code. You can make code more usable with ur view by adding various functions, loops, etc ,etc.
    int tagValue = 0;

    UITextField *newTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y+newYCoordinateForNewTxtFld, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    newTextField.delegate = self;
    newTextField.tag = tagValue++;
    frame = newTextField.frame;
    newTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [newTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.view addSubview:newTextField];

    newTextField = nil;
    newTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y+newYCoordinateForNewTxtFld, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    newTextField.tag = tagValue++;
    newTextField.delegate = self;
    frame = newTextField.frame;
    newTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [newTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.view addSubview:newTextField];

}
@end
```